# Starting/stopping upstart service when Digitalocean droplet is created (14.04)

Tags: virtualization, upstart

I'm running a node.js server on a Digitalocean droplet, and I want the server to announce that it's ready to an external service (via HTTP post).

The server runs via an upstart script using the "startup" event. The node.js server itself creates the post to the external service when it successfully starts.

But when I create the Droplet, it restores the machine to the original state (the node.js server is already up and running). So since the node.js server doesn't start, the post to the external service never happens.

Is there an alternative upstart event I can use that's not "startup"? One that would fire when a VM somes online?

I'm new to upstart, so I'm still trying to get my bearings with this tool, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is there some kind of resume script that is executed when the droplet is restored? If so, add the command `initctl emit --no-wait droplet-resumed` to the script, and then you will have the event `droplet-resumed` to signal when the thing is restored.